# Defined one to one relationship between 2 models but still seem to be able to build one to many

Tags: ruby-on-rails, one-to-one

Given two Rails models with one to one relationship. A WorkItem has one ChemicalSafetyFeature and a ChemicalSafetyFeature belongs to a WorkItem

```
class WorkItem < ActiveRecord::Base
  has_one :chemical_safety_feature
end 

class ChemicalSafetyFeature < ActiveRecord::Base    
  belongs_to :work_item
end
```

I go on to rails console and I create a WorkItem. I get a WorkItem object with id = 1

```
WorkItem.create()
```

Then I create one ChemicalSafetyFeature object like thisand test it out

```
ChemicalSafetyFeature.create(work_item: WorkItem.first)

ChemicalSafetyFeature.workItem == WorkItem.first
WorkItem.first.chemical_safety_feature == ChemicalSafetyFeature.first
```

But its surprising to me if I create another ChemicalSafetyFeature and link it to the first work item:

```
ChemicalSafetyFeature.create(work_item = WorkItem.first)
```

Even though ChemicalSafetyFeature.first.work_item and ChemicalSafetyFeature.find(2).work_item point to the first WorkItem, the first WorkItem points to only the first ChemicalSafetyFeature object. 
My expectations are that when I try to create the second ChemicalSafetyFeature object which is associated with the first WorkItem, it should throw an error. It seems like I can still create two ChemicalSafetyFeature objects which both link to the first WorkItem which means that the first WorkItem has 2 ChenicalSafetyFeature items

Comment: Was this a typo: `ChemicalSafetyFeature.create(work_item = WorkItem.first)`? I'd expect that should raise an exception because `create` should be expecting an options hash.

Comment: I think it's that you can make model associations, but they are not really associated if the foreing_key are non existent. For example, ChemicalSafetyFeature must have a work_item_id column with a reference. Rails writes directly in the database, and as the column just have one value, it's only possible to assign one single reference to that record (work_item_id: 2), for example.

Comment: Yes, `ChemicalSafetyFeature.create(work_item = WorkItem.first` was a typo. I have it fixed now. Thanks for pointing that out

Answer (score 0, accepted):

A `has_one` relationship does not enforce that the model with the `has_one` relationship only belongs to one object with the `belongs_to` relationship. It does not enforce that there is only a single `chemical_safety_features` record with that `work_item_id`.

You can enforce this with a uniqueness validation:

```rb
class ChemicalSafetyFeature < ActiveRecord::Base
  validates :work_item_id, uniqueness: true
  belongs_to :work_item
end
```

The way this validation works is by querying the database before saving the `ChemicalSafetyFeature` instance to check if there is already a record with that `work_item_id`. If a record is found it fails the save. It is still possible to violate this constraint due to a race condition.

Imagine there is no conflicting record in the database and two processes query the database for a record with `work_item_id = 5`, and neither process finds any records. Then both processes will save a record with `work_item_id = 5` violating the constraint.

The solution is to add a unique constraint in the database. This will ensure you cannot have two records with identical `work_item_id` values.

Create a migration with this `add_index` call:

`add_index :chemical_safety_features, :work_item_id, unique: true`

With this index the database will enforce the constraint, and the application code will not be able to violate the constraint.

You should also define `work_item_id` as a foreign key in the database using an `add_foreign_key` migration. This will prevent inserting garbage values to that field. It will also prevent orphaned records - you will not be able to delete a record from `work_items` if there is a reference to that record in the `chemical_safety_features` table.

Finally, you should tell rails what to do if you call `#destroy` on a `WorkItem` instance that belongs to a `ChemicalSafetyFeature`. Take a look at the `dependent` option for `has_one` and `has_many` relationships.

For example if you specify

```rb
class WorkItem < ActiveRecord::Base
  has_one :chemical_safety_feature, dependent: :destroy
end
```

Then calling `#destroy` on a `WorkItem` will call `destroy` on the related `ChemicalSafetyFeature`. Other values for the `dependent` option are `:delete`, `:nullify`, `:restrict_with_exception`, and `:restrict_with_error`.

It is good practice to always specify the `dependent` option on all `has_one` and `has_many` relationships.

Comment: Thanks for clearing it up for me! Really detailed explanation and I certainly needed that `validates :work_item_id, uniqueness: true`. I also specified  `dependent: :destroy` on my WorkItem model.

Comment: The case where you highlighted the constraint being vio;ated is interesting. I never thought that would happen but I guess it is possible in a production environment where two processes to create a ChemicalSafetyFeature model linking to the exact same WorkItem model could occur. That is something I definitely have to look into more